# Excel VBA Macros xlDays

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, linechart

I'm working on Line with markers chart. I have recorded a macro to create line chart (exactly `xlLineMarkers`). particularly x-axis with 7 days gap.
but it gives runtime error on

```
 ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnitScale = xlDays
```

I'm new to Excel VBA, please can anyone help?

Comment: it will be more clear if you provide your complete code here...

Comment: The question does not provide nearly enough information to solve the problem. Please add a [mcve].

Comment: Are you sure that your `CategoryType` is either `xlAutomatic` (and your data is dates) or `xlTimeScale`?  (It will crash if you have a `CategoryType` of `xlCategoryScale`.)

Comment: @YowE3K, You are right. i delete my answer.

Comment: @Dy.Lee LOL - we **all** get confused at various times.

Comment: @YowE3K,Thanks to your answers, we found something new. If the time data is on the x axis, the line graph can be used like a scatter graph, and now we can use .MajorUnitScale = xlDays, but we can not use "MajorUnitScale = xlDays" in the scatter graph. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

apparently that doesn't work for my problem
i want to pick max and min date from datasheet and then display on x axis b y 1 week difference. can anybody help please  ( in a deadlock :( )

```
[coding][1]
```

[line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iM7qg.png)

the code runs error free but doesnt show anything on x axis